# Display result with listener if radiobutton checked

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i need to display 24,36,60 in MonthsTxtView in each condition of if  when user check the coresponding radio button . For example if user check 2 years i need to display on MonthsTxtview the 24 and etc... Below is my code but when i am running and checking a radio button tolds me "Unfortunately,Carloan (name of app) has stopped" and closes my app any suggestion?

XML CODE:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.example.ioann_000.carloan.MainActivity"
        android:background="#E1E1E1"
        >
<TextView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/MonthsTxtView"
        android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Total2TxtView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Total2TxtView"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:background="@drawable/editetxt_second" />


         <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/RadioGroup1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LoadurationTextView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/InsertTextView">
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radioyear2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2 Years"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/RadioGroup1"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/RadioGroup1" />
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radioyear3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="3 Years"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radioyear5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="5 Years"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>

    </RadioGroup>
```

JAVA CODE:

```
  package com.example.ioann_000.carloan;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.Selection;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.NumberFormat;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "CARLOAN";
    private TextView MonthsTxtView;
    private TextView Total2TxtView;
    private RadioGroup RadioGroup1;
    private RadioButton selected;
    private int years2=24;
    private int years3=36;
    private int years5=60;
    private double MontlyI= 0;
    private double loan = 0;
    private RadioButton radioyear2;
    private RadioButton radioyear3;
    private RadioButton radioyear5;



    private static final NumberFormat currencyFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    private static final NumberFormat percentFormat = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MonthsTxtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MonthsTxtView);
        Total2TxtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Total2TxtView);
        radioyear2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioyear2);
        radioyear3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioyear3);
        radioyear5 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioyear5);
        EditText IREditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.IREditText);
        EditText AmountEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.AmountEditText);
        EditText AFEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.AFEditText);
        RadioBtn();
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: ");
    }


      private void RadioBtn () {

            RadioGroup selected= (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup1);
           selected.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
               @Override
               public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
                   if(radioyear2.isChecked()) {

                       MonthsTxtView.setText("24");
                       Log.i(TAG, "onCheckedChanged: ");

               }
                   else if (radioyear3.isChecked()) {

                       MonthsTxtView.setText("36");
                       Log.i(TAG, "onCheckedChanged: ");

                   }
                   else

                       MonthsTxtView.setText("60");
                   Log.i(TAG, "onCheckedChanged: ");

               }

      });
          Log.i(TAG, "RadioBtn: ");
      }

















}
```

ERROR when Clicking Radio Button:

```
**12-07 01:31:00.863 4006-4006/com.example.ioann_000.carloan E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.example.ioann_000.carloan, PID: 4006
                                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.widget.RadioButton.isChecked()' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at com.example.ioann_000.carloan.MainActivity$1.onCheckedChanged(MainActivity.java:64)
                                                                                 at android.widget.RadioGroup.setCheckedId(RadioGroup.java:174)
                                                                                 at android.widget.RadioGroup.access$600(RadioGroup.java:54)
                                                                                 at android.widget.RadioGroup$CheckedStateTracker.onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup.java:358)
                                                                                 at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:157)
                                                                                 at android.widget.CompoundButton.toggle(CompoundButton.java:113)
                                                                                 at android.widget.RadioButton.toggle(RadioButton.java:78)
                                                                                 at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:118)
                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
**
```

ERROR 2 : `E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.ioann_000.carloan, PID: 11445
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method onRadioButtonClicked(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton with id 'radioyear2'
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:327)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
                      at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:120)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8625', transport: 'socket'`

Comment: make `RadioGroup` a class field, i.e. declare it in the same place where you declare your `TextView`s. The correct idiom for `onCheckedChanged` is `switch(i) { case: R.id.radio1: //`. See the [official tutorial](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html)

Comment: can u be more analytic i mean can post a code?

Comment: have you read the tutorial? I would like to help more but I am at work right now. There is some example code in the [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html). If you haven't got it by tonight I will post a solution

Comment: Nice u were right , thanks a lot !

Comment: I'm really happy that you were able to do it yourself without other people having to post code for you! Well done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i have to do this change:

```
 `public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
        // Is the button now checked?
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        // Check which radio button was clicked
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.radioyear2:
                if (checked)
                    MonthsTxtView.setText("24");
                Log.i(TAG, "onRadioButtonClicked: ");
                    break;
            case R.id.radioyear3:
                if (checked)
                    MonthsTxtView.setText("36");
                Log.i(TAG, "onRadioButtonClicked: ");
                    break;
            case R.id.radioyear5:
                if (checked)
                    MonthsTxtView.setText("60");
                Log.i(TAG, "onRadioButtonClicked: ");
                break;
        }
    }
      }`
```

thanks to @David Rawson

Comment: if you think, this is the right answer, please mark it as the accepted answer, so it can helps the others

Comment: Did you have to move the `RadioGroup` to a class field and initialise it in `onCreate()`? If so, maybe you can edit your answer to put that in. Also, there is no need to thank me by name since you ended up solving the problem by yourself!

Answer (score 0):

One of your RadioButtons is outside the RadioGroup tag. Check that first. Regards!

The other thing you can do is something like bellow:

```
int checkedRadioButtonId = selected.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
if (checkedRadioButtonId == -1) {
    // No item selected
}
else{
    switch(checkedRadioButtonId){
       case R.id.radioyear2:
        // Do something cool here
       break;
       case R.id.radioyear3:
        // Do something cool here
       break;
       case R.id.radioyear5:
        // Do something cool here
       break;
    }
}
```

And also, you missed to initialize your MonthsTxtView with the findViewById...

Comment: Yea i see it , but again the same error when i am running it , "Unfortunately,Carloan (name of app) has stopped".

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like you initialized your radio buttons. You need to bind them to the variables using findViewById. It would also help if you posted the stack trace

In onCreate

```
radioyear2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioyear2);
radioyear3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioyear3);
radioyear5 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioyear5);

MonthsTxtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MonthsTxtView);
```

Comment: Also as MM. Charles said you will likely also need to initialize MonthsTxtView

Comment: See updated answer. As I mentioned, it would be very helpful if you posted your logcat stack trace. That will 100% identify the crash here.

Comment: where i will find this to post?

Comment: The logcat in Android Studio. I suggest you look into debugging applications before moving on. This is a crucial skill to have. See here: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html

Comment: i put logi but nothing show in monitor logcat when i am running it... check the code above again

Comment: Im going to need the logcat before I provide any more help. All I can tell is that you never initialize thosre views using findViewById. That means they are probably null which leads to the null pointer exception which crashes your app. It could be something else but it is not obvious. The logs will tell you exactly what lines the crash is happeneing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129948/discussion-between-jhk1821-and-rich-luick).

Comment: Unfortunately I am unavailable for the rest of the night. Id highly recommend taking a pause and learning how to debug especially with logcat. This is a very fundamental aspect of android development and would likely easily yield an answer to your issue. There are plenty of articles and youtube videos on this matter. I am sorry I am unable to help more :)

Comment: ok the code is updated now with the logcat when clicking on radiobutton

Comment: Okay so radio button is null at that line. The reason is that super.onCreate and setContentVirw are after the findViewById. Technically findVirwById will return null until you setContentView. Move super.onCreate and setContentView to the first line in onCreate

Comment: Sorry not sure off what I see. Im just on my phone. I would do a search for that error on stackoverflow. The IllegalStateException for onRadioButton clicked. You will probably find something. We have fixed the initial error. Thisnis probably something else.